# How to indent bash code with neovim?

Tags: neovim, indentation

I just installed neovim. But I not sure how to auto indent bash code. I have vim configured so that it can autoindent code. My `~/.vimrc` has the following code. But it seems that they will not be loaded with neovim.

```
fun BenIndent()
  let oldLine=line('.')
  normal gg=G
  execute ':' . oldLine
endfun
map -- :call BenIndent()<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

Neovim doesn't use the location `~/.vimrc` for its configuration file. Try moving, copying, or symlinking your file to the location:

```
~/.config/nvim/init.vim
```

Comment: I didn't see that bit :|

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the function as below:

```
function! BenIndent()
  let oldLine=line('.')
  normal! gg=G
  execute ':' . oldLine
endfunction
nnoremap -- :call BenIndent()<CR>
```

Should work now I think.

Here's what I changed from your function:

```
fun -> function! BenIndent()  " I've just always known functions to be declared this way, I may be wrong
  let oldLine=line('.')
  normal -> normal! gg=G      " the ! sign tells vim to not remap the provided keys, e.g. if you map g to :q then vim would quit when indenting!
  execute ':' . oldLine
endfun -> endfunction         " just my convention
map -> nnoremap -- :call BenIndent()<CR> " noremap tells vim not to use remapped keys and n is for mapping in normal mode only, if you want in other modes change n with v, i or c etc.
```

prefix of `->` is your code and suffix is mine.

Comment: I would reformat/reword this to highlight what you actually changed (i.e. `fun -> function` and `map -> nnoremap`. Your answer would also be better if you explained why these changes are necessary/good.